# Prove inequality for summation not by induction

Tags: inequality, summation

I have been thinking about the following inequality for some time. I think I can prove it by induction but is there more beautiful proof? (No, I don't consider proofs by induction beautiful. And yes, I believe that the beauty of proof is important.)

Let us say we have
$$
a_1 \ge a_2 \ge \dotsb \ge a_n \ge 0,
$$
$$
0 \le b_1 \le b_2 \le \dotsb \le b_n.
$$
How to prove that the following always holds:
$$
a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 + \dotsb + a_n b_n \le \frac 1n (a_1 + a_2 + \dotsb + a_n)(b_1 + b_2 + \dotsb + b_n)
$$

Comment: Look up [Chebyshev's sum inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality).

Comment: That was fast. And correct. Do you want to post it as an answer?